# How to use PHP to update prior HTML output with form submission on same page

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a form submission page (POST) that displays all current users (as checkbox objects at the beginning of the form), using file_get_contents() of an htpasswd file, and allows the user to update these users with the exec() function.  This all works correctly, except for the fact that the user list displayed on the page is not updated after the user submits their changes via the form submit button.  I know that the reason this happens is because the code to update the results occurs after the echo of the results.

So my question is: Is there any way to modify/update the output (with PHP) that would occur before the actual functions are executed?  I have included my basic code structure to help visualize my situation:

form.php:

```
<form method="post">

<?php
    //Code to read htpasswd file, then output results as form input checkboxes
?>

<select name="action">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="delete"></option>
    <option value="change"></option>
    <option value="create"></option>
</select>

<input type="submit">

<?php
    if($_POST['action'] !== '')
    {
        switch($_POST['action'])
        {
            case delete:
            //run exec() command to delete each user

            case change:
            //run exec() command to change pw for each user

            case create:
            //run exec() command to create a user
        }
    }
?>
```

If this is not possible with PHP, will Javascript do the job?

Comment: Wouldn't putting the last PHP code block before the first block that outputs the list work?

Comment: Basically, you want to update the page without reloading it, with the newly submitted info? If so you need to look into AJAX. (IMO the simplest method is using Jquery.) Or is it that the newly loaded page doesn't include the new info? Then the issue should be solved by changing the order of your PHP code, to make sure that all the processing is done before anything is displayed, simply.

Comment: Swapping the PHP code blocks worked like a charm!  Thanks j08691 and Ariane.  Is there no way to mark comments as answers?  Sorry, I am new here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of j08691 and Ariane, I was able to get the desired outcome by swapping the code as mentioned:

```
<form method="post">

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] !== '')
    {
        switch($_POST['action'])
        {
            case delete:
            //run exec() command to delete each user

            case change:
            //run exec() command to change pw for each user

            case create:
            //run exec() command to create a user
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    //Code to read htpasswd file, then output results as form input checkboxes
?>

<select name="action">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="delete"></option>
    <option value="change"></option>
    <option value="create"></option>
</select>

<input type="submit">
```